# Find equations of common tangents to two hyperbolas

Tags: conic-sections, tangent-line

I want to find equations of common tangents to two hyperbolas $\frac{x^{2}}{5}-\frac{y^{2}}{4}=1$ and $\frac{x^{2}}{4}-\frac{y^{2}}{3}=1$.
I think that I should use $y=mx+c$
then I will get something like $$\frac{4 x^{2}-5(m x+c)^{2}}{20}=1$$ for first equation.
What should I do for the rest?

Comment: What do you mean by common tangents?  These curves intersect at the points $(\pm 2\sqrt 5,\pm 2\sqrt 3)$.  The tangent lines to the respective curves at these points are not parallel.

Comment: You may need to spend more time thinking through the problem and edit your question to share additional context including your thoughts on the problem and a more sincere effort. Just as an example, if the tangent is common to both hyperbola, you can equate the slopes of tangent of both hyperbolas. How do you find slope of the tangent of a curve?

Comment: @MarkViola that's a good point. I guess $x, y$ are swapped in one of the equations. To OP, please draw the given curves and check.

Comment: @MarkViola https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/the-equations-to-the-common-tangents-to-the-two-hyperbolas-displaystyle-fracx2a2-fracy2b2/  tangent line like solved in this link

Comment: @booker Define "common tangent."  In the referenced problem, Equation (ii) makes no sense since $\sqrt{-b^2m^2-a^2}$ is not even a real number.

Comment: In the linked question, you need to first notice the equations of hyperbolas $x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 = 1$ and $y^2/a^2 - x^2/b^2 = 1$. That is exactly my earlier comment.

Comment: Whereas  in the question you have posted, both hyperbola have same transverse axis and they intersect. It does not have common tangents unless you have typed in equations incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: common tangent]

The dual conics $X^2/4-Y^2/5-1/20=0, X^2/3-Y^2/4-1/12=0$ do intersect in $(X,Y)=(-1,-1),(-1,1),(1,-1),(1,1),$ making the common tangents $-x-y+1=0,-x+y+1=0,x-y+1=0,x+y+1=0.$